# Reduce choice list in select2 dropdown (when searching)

Tags: javascript, symfony, jquery-select2

When I use select2, the list of choice doesn't reduce while searching, which is pretty annoying when I have more than 50 choices..

I use symfony4 framework, with a route providing my tags that are in a DB:

```
/**
 * @Route("/miseenpage/keywords.json", name="keywords", defaults={"_format": "json"})
 */
```

Then I init my select2 with this code provided by the [symfony Tags plugin](https://github.com/Bee-Lab/BeelabTagBundle):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    initTags($('input[name$="[tagsText]"]'));
});

// TAGS
function initTags($input) {
    if($input.length) {
        $input.attr('type', 'hidden').select2({
            width: '85%',
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
                if ($(data).filter(function () {
                    return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
                }).length === 0) {
                    return {
                        id: term,
                        text: term
                    };
                }
            },
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
                url: $input.data('ajax'),
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            },
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var data = [];

                function splitVal(string, separator) {
                    var val, i, l;
                    if (string === null || string.length < 1) {
                        return [];
                    }
                    val = string.split(separator);
                    for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i = i + 1) {
                        val[i] = $.trim(val[i]);
                    }
                    return val;
                }

                $(splitVal(element.val(), ",")).each(function () {
                    data.push({
                        id: this,
                        text: this
                    });
                });
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the result in my webpage before searching:
[image]

Here is after searching:
[image]

As you can see, the list is still the same, just the result is underlined. I'd like to filter the result depending on what I search, so I don't have to scroll all the way until I find my underlined term.

As it is the basic working of [Select2](https://select2.org/tagging), I guess there is an configuration problem in my JS.

Comment: Hi, may be a stupid question but why do you init your select2 on input type hidden ? (are sure you're initializing the good input). Btw, a good pratice is to load the result after at least X characters entered (to avoid querying multiple times your server). Your JS looks really complicated compared to what you want to do...

Comment: I used the [cookbook](https://github.com/Bee-Lab/BeelabTagBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/javascript.md) from the Tags plugin for symfony, so I didn't edit the code as I though the behavior should be the same as a regular select2 ? Apart for the list not reducing, all is working perfectly though

Comment: That looks way too complicated for what it does (we use lots of nativ select2 in all our projects). Which version of Select2 are you using ?
Can you debug you keywords function to see if you really get what user types in the field ?

Comment: using select2 v3.5.3. As it is a select that should be populated (object in DB), it can already have some values inside on load (That's part of the added code from a regular select2 i think). I found a workaround, pretty sure it's the not the right one but working though. I post the code below.

Comment: The already loaded values are set with the `initSelection` part. If it's sufficient to your needs (it may be the case with only 50 values), you should remove all the ajax part. If it's not (if you have to dynamically load objects from DB), let me know and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Well, all the objects are coming from "/miseenpage/keywords.json" (which is a route, not a file), so the data is loaded each time from this url I guess ? (from the ajax part). And I overrided the select form in S4 with this attribute: 'data-ajax' => $this->router->generate('keywords').

Comment: Wooo ok I think I understand... In your function, do you get the `q`parameter you're passing throught ajax ? I guess you're not filtering the results according to what user is typing in the select2 field...

Comment: Yes I do get the q term from what I type with a console.log (look at the answer I typed below, I changed a few things there in the AJAX part so I made it work, but not really clean)

Comment: Ok yeah in the keywords.json route, I always give the whole list, it's never pre-processed. So I can either process it after in JS or before in PHP right ?

Comment: Haaaaa, finally I get the answer :D Yes, you can do it in php like I did in my answer. Your answer is quitte a bad trick as filtering via JS doesn't require Ajax. (just initialise your select field with `$("#myField").select2();`)

Comment: Once again, if the tags in your DB are not regularly updated and are not so many, I would just load them on page rendering and remove all the ajax part of your js code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help :) ! I think i'm almost there. I pre-fetch my tags in the controller, create a json formatted of all (with id, text & selected attributes), but then I need to send it in my tags.js file so I instanciate the select2. I call that script from my twig view: <script src="{{ asset('js/tags.js') }}"></script>. Do I instanciate another script block with like a "tagData" variable before I call that file ?

Comment: In the end it's not been working because the TAG addon element register a string in DB (so it's a text field). When I instanciate select2 with an input and a "data" field (without AJAX), I can't make it work properly. If I try to use a select instead of an input, I have a "This value is not valid" when I try to validate the form.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I instanciated this value on load:

```
let currentSearch = false;
```

Then I changed the "AJAX" section of my JS so it loops around the list with the searched value:

```
        ajax: {
            url: $input.data('ajax'),
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (term) {
                currentSearch = term;
                return {
                    q: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                let returnTab = [];
                data.forEach(function(e) {
                    if(e.text.includes(currentSearch)){
                        returnTab.push(e);
                    }
                });
                return {
                    results: returnTab
                };
            }
        },
```

I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner/simpler way of doing this, but for moment it's a quickfix.

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic example with some code to show how we use Select2 (v4.0.3, 3.5 may be quite different) with Ajax

On a twig, we have for example :

```
$("#users").css('width', '100%').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ path('api_search_user') }}",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 500,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        needle: params.term // Here we send user input to the controller
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: false
            }
        });
```

And we have a controller with a function to search for users :

```
/**
 * @Route("/search_users", name="api_search_users")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function searchUsersAction(Request $request)
{
    $needle = $request->get('needle'); // Here we retrieve user input
    $users = $this->get(User::class)->searchUsers($needle);
    return new JsonResponse($users );
}
```

**EDIT** following you last comment

> This value is not valid

That's because your value isn't part of the select when the formbuilder add the field. You must add an `addEventListener` on `PRE_SUBMIT` to dinamically add this value. You can do it this way :

```
// Define form modifier
$usersFormModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $users) use ($options) {
    $choices = array();
    if(is_array($users)) {
        $choices = $users;
    }

    $form->add(
        'users',
        EntityType::class,
        array(
            'label' => 'conversation.form.users',
            'multiple' => true,
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Security\User',
            'choices' => $choices,
            'choice_label' => function (User $user) {
                return $user->getLastName() . " " . $user->getFirstName();
            },
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'default.search_person'
            )
        )
    );
};

// On PRE_SET_DATA, we load users from our object (which only contains their IDs)
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($usersFormModifier) {
        $usersFormModifier($event->getForm(), $event->getData()->getUsers()->toArray());
    }
);

// On PRE_SUBMIT, we add the options, so the select will accept newly added values
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($usersFormModifier) {
        $data = $event->getData();

        $users = null;
        if(isset($data['users'])) {
            $users = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Security\User')->findBy(array('id' => $data['users']));
        }

        $usersFormModifier($event->getForm(), $users);
    }
);
```

As I said at the beginning, if you don't have so muchs tags, and they don't evolve regularly, you can construct your select with all your tags and avoid all the Ajax part of the Select2 javascript code ! (I think it will be easier and sufficient for your case)